# clearInterval doesn't clearInterval

Tags: javascript, function, setinterval, dom-events, clearinterval

```
var timer;

function check_element_load(){
    timer = window.setInterval(function(){
        console.log("still working"); // keeps running forever
        if(document.getElementById("comments")){
            console.log("FOUND"); // this actually runs
            document.getElementsByTagName("fb:comments")[0].setAttribute('order_by', 'social');
            window.clearInterval(timer); // < not effective
        }
    }, 50);
}


check_element_load();
```

I'm trying to put a script on top to keep checking if a specific element was successfully loaded in the browser, it works *(the console logged " FOUND ")*, but  when I wrote another console log to see if the interval still running. it does, it never stops and the `clearInterval` is completely ignored

is there anything that I missed ? I also tried using all other solutions including `settimeout` and the closest one to me now is the written, I just want the `clearinterval` to take effect after the condition returns true.

Is there anything similar to `clearinterval` that is more effective, kills the whole function or something?

Comment: Is the line ever hit? There might be an error on the `document.getElementsByTagName...` line.

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin this line works fine, everything takes effect and works properly except for the clearinterval

Comment: Not that this makes any difference, but why do you have two `timer` variables?

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin nice catch, thought it could be causing it, just tried to remove the `var` and same result. edited

Comment: @Osa what is the markup for this... `document.getElementsByTagName("fb:comments")[0].setAttribute('order_by', 'social');`

Comment: it adds an attribute to the `fb:comments` tag

Comment: @Osa i know what it does... I am asking for you to provide the markup. i.e. what does that tag look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it stands, your [code is logical correct](http://jsfiddle.net/vU9dm/), however if

```
document.getElementsByTagName("fb:comments")[0].setAttribute('order_by', 'social');
```

throws an error, (of course) the timeout will [never be cleared](http://jsfiddle.net/vU9dm/1/). You could [use `SetTimeout` instead](http://jsfiddle.net/vU9dm/2/).

Most likely calling `getElementsByTagName("fb:comments")` returns an empty set, giving you an "method setAttribute does not exist on Element undefined" Type Error.

Comment: the line you're talking about is alright, it would return false/error with you because you dont have the facebook (`fb:comments`) tags xmlns set, you can test on a normal tag, however i just tried to completely remove that line and i get the same result
looks like the problem is from the `if` condition, it doesn't properly return `true`, the point of it is to check if the element exists

Comment: @Osa This cannot be the case since you stated that the console.log("found") is executed. So the error *has to be* on exactly that line. Or there is some other code interfering with your code that you didn't post here.

Comment: @Osa The only problem I could think of is that perhaps you have some other code messing with the `timer` variable?

Comment: the only running code is the one i wrote, nothing messes with it, i just tried everything and it seems the most confusing code i have been through, im pretty sure the problem is coming from the browser or the computer is messing up, however i think ill take another direction, im just trying to append a facebook sort by attribute, i think this can be done from the default facebook sdk settings instead of adding an attribute or something

Comment: @Osa This might indeed be the better way. In case you sort this problem out, write an answer and accept it to mark your problem as solved. I'm really interested in how this problem occured.