# clearInterval on "OFF" payload

Tags: setinterval, node-red, clearinterval

I am having newbie difficulties implementing clearInterval with a certain payload.
The

> if(msg.payload.state === "OFF")

works, but the timer doesn't stop.

Amongst many resources, I have seen [how to stop setInterval in JS in node-red..?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55566703/how-to-stop-setinterval-in-js-in-node-red), [node.js: how to use setInterval and clearInterval?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46588994/node-js-how-to-use-setinterval-and-clearinterval), [clearInterval doesn't clearInterval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15877832/clearinterval-doesnt-clearinterval) & [clearInterval On Image Slider Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17769665/clearinterval-on-image-slider-plugin)

I did have a similar function, "dominos" that I used to make sure I was parsing the "OFF" payload.
I have included a lot of commented code to show what I had tried. Sorry about the mess!

Is it an issue with my syntax?

Is the code logical?

```
var input = msg.payload.state;
let timer = 0;

var red = {"state":"ON","brightness":255,"color":{"r":255,"g":0,"b":0}};
var green = {"state":"ON","brightness":255,"color":{"r":0,"g":255,"b":0}};


function xmas() {    // REPEATS!
    node.send({payload:red});
    setTimeout(function(){
        node.send({payload:green});
    }, 1500);
}
// repeat with 3 second interval
timer = setInterval(() => xmas(), 3000);
if (msg.payload.state === "OFF") {
    timer = clearInterval();
}
```

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59349301/edit) the code to remove all the commented out sections, Qeustions should contains a Minimal Viable example. Also is all of that code meant to be in a `function` node?

Comment: I could, but you did it for me, didn't you? Well, I am not sure if it is supposed to all be within the function. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important thing to remember about a function node is that it's state is totally reset for each incoming message. This means that timer will ALWAYS be reset to zero by the `let timer = 0;`

If you want to store any state between messages then you need to use the [context](https://nodered.org/docs/user-guide/writing-functions#storing-data).

Also the way you are using `clearInterval()` will never work, you need to pass the reference to the timer object to this function for it to do anything useful.

The following function node should do what I think you intended.

```
var red = {"state":"ON","brightness":255,"color":{"r":255,"g":0,"b":0}};
var green = {"state":"ON","brightness":255,"color":{"r":0,"g":255,"b":0}};


if (msg.payload.state != "OFF") {
   var timer = setInteval(()=>{
      node.send({payload: red});
      setTimeout(() => {
           node.send({payload: green});
      }, 1500);
   }, 3000);
   context.set("timer",timer);
} else {
   var timer = context.get("timer");
   clearInterval(timer);
}
```

Comment: Awesome! I was hoping to try it last night, but that wasn't possible. I'll update ASAP

Comment: Thanks [hardillb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/504554/hardillb)! Although the off payload isn't strictly necessary, I needed to edit more than 6 characters to be able to save the two typos.